# ksh - Add command line arguments to array

Tags: arrays, arguments, ksh

I have a script that takes in three command line arguments: 1) an infile, 2) an outfile, and 3) a single number to be added to the infile.

I would like to modify this script such that it can take any number of arguments similar to argument (3) above, and create an individual outfile based on each.  I believe the best way to achieve this (that I know of) is to assign all arguments after argument (2) to an array, and then use a for loop to iterate through the array.

It seems easy enough to create an array using the following code:

```
set -A arrayName "$@"
```

My question is, how exactly would I assign only arguments 3 onward to an array while allowing for any number of arguments greater than two?

Answer (score 0):

forgive me if this is too simple a solution. But no need to create an array, just look through the numbers to append:

```
echo 'start'
echo 'usage: my_prog.ksh infile outfile numtoappend [...]'
echo '$*'
echo $*

echo 'infile: ' $1
infile=$1
shift
echo 'outfile: ' $1
outfile=$1
shift
cat $infile > $outfile

echo 'starting loop: '
until [[ $# -eq 0 ]];do
   echo '$numbers to append'
   echo $1
   echo $1 >> $outfile
   shift
done
echo 'end'
```